# Coldfusion URL variable changes unexpectedly

Tags: apache, coldfusion

I have an issue that is greatly vexing me.  I have written a basic pagination tool for a page that is running on Coldfusion 11:  http://fftoolbox.scout.com/ffwc/rankings.cfm?rankings=season&page=2

I have designed it such that there is a url query called page that holds the page number.  This way, the user can just type in the page number that he desires rather than having to press the next and previous buttons.

The pagination works just fine for pages 1 - 25, but on page 26 and after, it records the url.page variable as 1, even though the link on the control clearly shows that the variable should be page 26.

If you will notice, I have coldfusion dumping the URL scope at the top of the page.  You will note that when the page is equal to 25 or less, the page is reported correctly.  Any value over 25, though, url.page is assigned a value 1, even though that is not what is being sent according to the browser.  I have tested this in FF, Chrome, and IE, and all exhibit the same behavior.  This leads me to believe that it is not something in the code or a browser based peculiarity, but possibly some sort of server setting.

Here is some assorted code of the project:

1. The dump and setting the session variables.

   ```
   <cfdump var='#url#'>
   <cfif not StructKeyExists(url,'page')>
       <cfset session.page = 1>
   <cfelse>
       <cfset session.page = url.page>
   </cfif>

   <cfset startingRank =  (session.page - 1)*50 +1>
   <cfset endingRank = (session.page - 1)*50 +50>
   ```

This starting and ending rank are used in an SQL query to retrieve the proper range of players.  I am not including the SQL unless someone requests it as that is working fine.  In fact, when I hard code the url.page to be 26, everything works as it is supposed to.

2. The Previous and Next links:

   ```
   <tr><td colspan='2' style='text-align: center'>
   <cfif session.page gt 1>
       <a href='./rankings.cfm?rankings=season&action=#Evaluate(session.page - 1)#'>Previous</a>
   </cfif></td>
   <td colspan='2' style='text-align: center'>
   <cfif session.page lt Evaluate(Int((GetMax.recordCount -1)/50) +1)>
        <a href='./rankings.cfm?rankings=season&page=#Evaluate(session.page + 1)#'>Next</a>
   </cfif></td></tr>
   ```

Please let me know if you need any more information.  I am thinking that this is actually either an Apache issue or a CF one as the pagination is working properly on pages 1 through 25.

EDIT:

I have had a request to show the queries.  There are two of them.  One to get the data and another to get the count of the entire set of data.

```
<cfquery name='GetData' datasource='XXXXXXXX'>
    select * from
        (select @currentRank := @currentRank +1 as rank,player_name, point_sum, contest_type from
           (select player_name,sum(points) as point_sum, contest_type, (select @currentRank := 0) r
             from 2014_ranking_season
             inner join ecom_item_type on ecom_item_type.ecom_item_type_id = 2014_ranking_season.contest_type
             where contest_type = #session.filter#
             group by player_name)t1
        order by point_sum desc)t2
    where rank between #startingRank# and #endingRank#
</cfquery>

<cfquery name='GetMax' datasource='XXXXXXXX'>
    select * from
        (select @currentRank := @currentRank +1 as rank,player_name, point_sum, contest_type from
           (select player_name,sum(points) as point_sum, contest_type, (select @currentRank := 0) r
             from 2014_ranking_season
             inner join ecom_item_type on ecom_item_type.ecom_item_type_id = 2014_ranking_season.contest_type
             where contest_type = #session.filter#
             group by player_name)t1
        order by point_sum desc)t2
</cfquery>
```

I hope that helps.  Please bear in mind that except for the previous button with which I am experimenting, everything works fine until page > 25.

EDIT:

The value for GetMax.recordCount = 2242.  Also, I am writing a small reproduction page that is scaled down to just produce the results.  Once it is done, I will post the code of the entire page.  Whether or not it reproduces the result it will tell us SOMETHING.

EDIT:

The reproduction page is in place and the error IS reproducible, even with the scaled down code.  Here is the URL:  http://fftoolbox.scout.com/ffwc/testPagination.cfm?rankings=season&page=26

Here is the entire code listing:

```
<cfdump var='#url#'>

<cfset session.page = 1>

<cfif StructKeyExists(url,'page')>
        <cfset session.page = url.page>
</cfif>

<cfset startingRank =  (session.page - 1)*50 +1>
<cfset endingRank = (session.page - 1)*50 +50>

<cfif not StructKeyExists(session,'filter')>
        <cfset session.filter = 0>
</cfif>

<cfparam name="url.rankings" default="season">

<html>
    <head>
            <title>Test Pagination</title>
    </head>
    <body>

                    <br /><br />
<cfoutput>

    <table width='99%' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'><tr class='header'>
    <cfset count = 0>
            <cfquery name='GetData' datasource='fftoolbox_sql'>
                    select * from
                            (select @currentRank := @currentRank +1 as rank,player_name, point_sum, contest_type from
                                    (select player_name,sum(points) as point_sum, contest_type, (select @currentRank := 0) r
                                    from 2014_ranking_season
                                    inner join ecom_item_type on ecom_item_type.ecom_item_type_id = 2014_ranking_season.contest_type
                                    group by player_name)t1
                            order by point_sum desc)t2
                    where rank between #startingRank# and #endingRank#
            </cfquery>
            <cfquery name='GetMax' datasource='fftoolbox_sql'>
                    select * from
                            (select @currentRank := @currentRank +1 as rank,player_name, point_sum, contest_type from
                                    (select player_name,sum(points) as point_sum, contest_type, (select @currentRank := 0) r
                                    from 2014_ranking_season
                                    inner join ecom_item_type on ecom_item_type.ecom_item_type_id = 2014_ranking_season.contest_type
                                    group by player_name)t1
                            order by point_sum desc)t2
            </cfquery>
            <th>RANK</th><th>PLAYER NAME</th><th>TEAM NAME</th><th>POINTS</th></tr>
            <cfloop query='GetData'>
                    <cfquery name='GetOneName' datasource='fftoolbox_sql'>
                            select team_name
                            from 2014_ranking_season
                            where player_name = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='CF_SQL_VARCHAR' value='#GetData.player_name#'>
                            limit 1
                    </cfquery>
                    <cfset name = URLEncodedFormat(#player_name#)>
                    <tr <cfif #count#%2 eq 0>class='evenRow'<cfelse>class='oddRow'</cfif>><td>#rank#</td>
                            <td><a href='./player.cfm?name=#variables.name#' target='_blank'>#player_name#</a></td><td>#GetOneName.team_name#</td><td>#point_sum#</td></tr>
                            <cfset count++>
            </cfloop>
            <tr><td colspan='2' style='text-align: center'>
            <cfif session.page gt 1>
                    <a href='./testPagination.cfm?rankings=season&page=#Evaluate(session.page - 1)#'>Previous</a>
                                                                    </cfif></td>
            <td colspan='2' style='text-align: center'>
            <cfif session.page lt Evaluate(Int((GetMax.recordCount -1)/50) +1)>
                    <a href='./testPagination.cfm?rankings=season&page=#Evaluate(session.page + 1)#'>Next</a>
            </cfif></td></tr>

    </table>
</cfoutput>
        </body>
</html>
```

I will also get the http request headers to display on that page.  I will put them in the question, if people want, but the question is starting to get long, and the cfdump formats it nicely in the browser.  Thank you, everyone for the interaction so far.

UPDATE:

I am suspecting that our provisioning team, over whom I have no control, might have done something on the backend, such as put it on Varnish, which is not supposed to happen.  Please continue to look at the code, etc, and I will bark up this tree to see if there is something they have done.  25 just seems like to "human" a number for it not to be a setting somewhere.  I will keep you posted.

UPDATE:

I have checked with the provisioning team, and Varnish is not active, and the load balance is NOT causing the issue, as I could replicate the issue when bypassing the LB.  My opinion that it is a configuration issue with Apache or CF seems to be becoming more and more likely as we rule things out.

UPDATE:

Upon adding the code that @Leigh recommended, we find that the http request is definitely page=26, and the URL scope is definitely page=1.  I am looking to see if an Application file might be messing with it.

FINAL UPDATE:

Upon examining the Application.cfm, I found the following code:

```
<cfif cgi.script_name NEQ "/ffwc/all-time-leaderboard.cfm">
    <cfset ValidPages = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25">
    <cfif IsDefined("url.page") and ListFind(ValidPages,url.page) eq 0>
            <cfset url.page = 1>
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

After this was commented out, the pagination worked just fine.  Another alternative method of making it work would be to not use page as the variable name for the page.  (This is counter intuitive and distasteful to me) I hold the opinion that constructs like pagination should be contained within one file or directory, and not be site wide.

Comment: Is this all in one CFM?

Comment: Well, evidently the comments must be 15 characters in length, but the answer is yes.  It is all one cfm.

Comment: First off, you mentioned a "dump", but I do not see anything above. Did you dump the variables to examine the values when the problem occurs? For example, what are the values of `endingRank` (not sure how it is used), `url.page`, `Evaluate(Int((GetMax.recordCount -1)/50) +1)`, etcetera. Side note a) no need for `evaluate()` and b) the previous link always returns you to page 1 because it is not passing the `url.page` parameter.

Comment: Dump is the first line of the code.  It dumps the URL scope to the browser every time it loads.  It does this in the very first line of code on the page, so there is no other code running before that.  Also, yes, I have examined all the variables, and they are, indeed wrong when page>26, because the server receives it as page=1 in the first line of code.  I understand that there is no particular need for evaluate.  It is vestigial from from before I cast the math result as an integer.  I understand the previous link is broken, as I am using that to experiment with.

Comment: As @Leigh mentioned earlier, I would suspect that the page variable is no longer being passed in the URL after page 25. Then your code is re-setting the `session.page` variable back to 1.

Comment: @stubsthewizard - I meant you did not post the results of the dump here Since we cannot see the actual values, we can only make guesses.  *RE: they are, indeed wrong when page>26 because the server receives it as page=1 in the first line of code* No, if you pass `&page=26` as a url parameter, the server will receive `url.page=26`.  Unless something else is manipulating the url parameters somehow ...

Comment: (Edit) BTW, I see the same result, but .. URL parameters do not just change on their own.  Something else is going on.  It would help to post [small, standalone repro case](http://www.sscce.org/) others could test (use queryNew + loop to simulate db queries).  Is there any other code executing before the dump - on that page, in your Application.cfc, etc... ? Also, dump `getHTTPRequestData()`.

Comment: Hi @leigh.  Thank you for the comments.  I appreciate your attention to this matter.  We are in agreement, the server should be receiving page=26.  Between the browser sending it and the very first line of the code, though it is changed to 1.  This is why I am suspecting Apache or Coldfusion configuration, rather than the code. I am building a standalone repro case right now, and I will dump the http request data and post it here.

Comment: Can you add a dump of `getHTTPRequestData()` to the test page?

Comment: @Leigh Done.  I am not sure how helpful that will be, though.  I had thought it would include the URL query, but either it doesn't or I am missing it.

Comment: @stubsthewizard - Drat... it might not include it for GET requests.  Let me try a test on a local machine. BTW, do you have createObject("java") access ?  Reason for asking is there are java alternatives you can use for debugging, but they require createObject().

Comment: I should have that access.  Please let me know any technique you need me to try.  You have to admit, this is a strange and challenging issue! :-D

Comment: (Edit) @stubsthewizard - Actually try the built in getPageContext() function ie `getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterMap()` instead.  BTW, I put together a crude test page (sans query) and it works as expected.  http://pastebin.com/nmp8eafn Try it and let us see what results you get. (Also, did you say you checked for something else that might be modifying parameters like an Application file, server filter, etcetera... )

Comment: lol.  It asked me to move our discussion to chat, but then when I tried, it said I need one more reputation point.  Would upvoting my question give me a reputation point?  I DO agree that it would be better to chat, as I think we are getting this figured out.  I do not know if the Application file is changing anything, as I did not write it, and have not really looked at it too much.  I will look into that, and post it, if that helps. I will also output the function you mentioned on our test page.

Comment: Done.  REALLY interesting result.  It confirms my theory that the browser is sending it properly, but either Apache or CF is intercepting it.  I am looking through the Application.cfc file.

Comment: Wow... I just read your last update. I can't even... why was that even there?

Comment: I assume that whomever wrote it made a file that would have 25 pages, and he wanted to limit the user to being able to select only 25 pages.  The difficult thing to fathom is why would you EVER make that a global setting??!!  Someone wrote it in 2009, and there it sat for all these years waiting to bite me!  lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon examining the Application.cfm, I found the following code:

```
<cfif cgi.script_name NEQ "/ffwc/all-time-leaderboard.cfm">
    <cfset ValidPages = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25">
    <cfif IsDefined("url.page") and ListFind(ValidPages,url.page) eq 0>
            <cfset url.page = 1>
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

After this was commented out, the pagination worked just fine. Another alternative method of making it work would be to not use page as the variable name for the page. (This is counter intuitive and distasteful to me) I hold the opinion that constructs like pagination should be contained within one file or directory, and not be site wide.

Thank you to all that commented, and helped me in this endeavor.

Comment: Oh my lord I think my head might explode.

Comment: Yes.  I am cleaning up my office right now from my head doing the same thing!  lol.  Thank you for your comments!

Comment: (Edit): *RE: constructs like pagination should ..not be site wide.* Yes, this is a good example why.  (Also agreed about paginating in the database instead). Good job.  I am not going to write up a separate answer, as I think the above covers it :) However, I would add a note (for future readers) that using `getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterMap()` allows you to view parameter values received by the servlet. Comparing that against the final value in the URL scope indicated something was changed in the Application file or CF code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your "previous" button isn't setting a `URL.page` or `session.page` - it's using "action." Since `page` isn't defined in the URL it automatically sets the page to one... So clicking "previous" and then "next" always sets me back to page 2 no matter where I start.

Now, your "next" link...

```
 <cfif session.page lt Evaluate(Int((GetMax.recordCount -1)/50) +1)>
    <a href='./rankings.cfm?rankings=season&page=#Evaluate(session.page + 1)#'>Next</a>
 </cfif>
```

I just ran this code after setting `session.page` on my own .cfm page...

A "Next" button will only ever show up if `session.page` is zero or `GetMax.recordcount` is more than 50x the value of `session.page`. I raise issue with that because GetMax.recordcount shouldn't ever change. You're displaying 50 records at a time.

The following code doesn't work so I don't what you're doing on your end...

```
<cfset GetMax.recordcount = 50>
<cfset session.page = 1>

<cfoutput>
<cfif session.page lt Evaluate(Int((GetMax.recordCount -1)/50) +1)>
     <a href='./rankings.cfm?rankings=season&page=#Evaluate(session.page + 1)#'>Next</a>
</cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

It might be time to show us the query logic.

### Edit:

Why not do something like this?

```
<cfset StartRecord = #url.page# * 50 - 49>

<cfquery name="listOfPeople" datasource="XXX">
SELECT TOP 50 *
FROM PeopleTable
WHERE PeopleID >= #StartRecord#
</cfquery>
```

It's so simple and I'm just not getting why the query `GetMax` is needed. All that extra math involved just heightens the risk for error. Pagination shouldn't be a project unto itself.

Comment: Hi Guys.  Please do not get hung up on the usage of the buttons.  I have kept the "next" button working as it should, but am experimenting with the previous button.  The issue is that when page>25, it is sent to the browser as 1.  As to the queries, I run two.  The GetData query only returns 50.  The GetMax query does not include the range, and is only used to get the record count of the entire set.   That was a good catch, though.  I will put the queries into the question, although they seem to be working just fine.

Comment: Could you please share the value for GetMax.recordcount? It seems like something that won't change all that often so I'd like to use it in some code I'm running.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  I appreciate your help.  The value of GetMax.recordCount is 2242.  This is withe the All Contests filter selected.  I am making another page to test with.  I will also put the value of the GetMax.recordCount in the question.

Comment: The math still seems a little fuzzy to me... but I can't poke any more holes in it and you might be onto something with that Varnish thing you mentioned in your last edit. I edited my answer with one more suggestion but it may not prove at all helpful. I'm just curious why you did things the way you did.

Comment: I appreciate your comment.  Believe me, I would rather do it the way that you are indicating, and in fact we used to when the rank was stored.  We now have to calculate the rank on the fly, and that added an order of magnitude to the complexity. Although I would rather have done the pagination in SQL, I just used a second query as an expedient.

Comment: *Why not do something like this?*  That logic will not work.  To use TOP (or similar operators) in that manner requires that the results are sorted. Without an ORDER BY clause, the end results are kind of meaningless.  Assuming PeopleID is some sort of numeric ID, it would only work reliably if the results were sorted by PeopleID, which they are not.

Comment: @Leigh It was just a sloppily put together query to emphasize that there were easier ways. Turns out it wasn't the wizard's actual issue though, so no biggie.

Comment: @TRose - Yeah, I figured but ... you never know who is going to read the answer in the future ;-) Chances are good someone is going to try it down the road, not realizing the logic does really not work because it does not cause a hard error.  There are some nice SQL Server features that might help here like row_number() and calculated columns. Unfortunately, it looks like he is using MySQL, which AFAIK does not have equivalent functionality.